# How would you retrieve N characters using regex from an existing regex?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I would need to retrieve an email id from a email address.
(i.e. this-is-the-best.email@gmail.com => this-is-the-best.email)

The regex that I used is `(.*)@.*` .

Now I need truncate the string with N characters.
(i.e. N=7 => this-is N=30 =>this-is-the-best.email)

How would I add this to a existing regex?
Any other recommendations?

Comment: Match the first 7 characters that are not an @ char?

Answer (score 0):

What about: `([^@]{1,7}).+`?

```
this-is-the-best-email@gmail.com
short@hotmail.co.uk
```

Becomes:

```
this-is
short
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are looking for:

```
((.{1,7}).*)@.+
```

The first capturing group contains the full id and the second group contains up to 7 chars.

Comment: I think you have an extra pair of parentheses.  Should be `(.{1,7}).*@.+`.

Comment: @sindri_baldur I left them there to be possible to also retrieve the full id as the first group, but if the full id is not needed, the parentheses could be removed as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern `(.*)@.*` you don't need the trailing `.*` as it is optional, and the dot can match any character including spaces and the @ itself which can match much more that just an email like address.

---

The thing of interest is the non whitespace chars excluding an @ char before actually matching the @, and in that case you can use a capture group matching 7 non whitespace chars.

```
([^\s@]{7})[^\s@]*@
```

The pattern matches:

- `([^\s@]{7})` Capture **group 1**, match 7 non whitespace chars excluding @
- `[^\s@]*` Optionally match any non whitespace char excluding @
- `@` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aMUoSm/1)